# How can we change this PHP function to work with PHP 8?

Tags: php, function, rewriting

Would anyone know how we can rewrite the following function to be compatible and work with PHP 8?

```php
function wpsc_have_shipping_quote() {

    $has_quote = false;

    global $wpsc_cart;

    if ( $wpsc_cart->shipping_quote_count > 0 || count( $wpsc_cart->shipping_quotes ) > 0 ) {
        $has_quote = true;
    }

    return $has_quote;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with that function as it stands? I'm not seeing anything jumping out at me. Are you getting an error when you use it?

Comment: What does not work with this?

Comment: Hi there, sorry forgot to post the error message, which is:Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given

Comment: Before upgrading the PHP version of a site, always turn PHP errors completely on. This has been a warning since 7.2 with a plan to turn it into a full error in 8.0.

Comment: Thanks Chris, Luckily we're doing this in a test environment at the moment. Currently trying to upgrade from PHP7.4 to PHP8.0. The other section of code with the $value mentioned is: function wpsc_shipping_quote_value( $numeric = false ) {
   global $wpsc_cart;

   $value = apply_filters( 'wpsc_shipping_quote_value', $wpsc_cart->shipping_quote['value'] );

   return ( $numeric ) ? $value : wpsc_currency_display( $value );

}

Comment: Assuming `$wpsc_cart->shipping_quotes` is an array and not an exotic object, you can simply check for `!empty($wpsc_cart->shipping_quotes)` which will return true if 1 or more, and false on 0 or null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to count the array just to see if it has anything in it. When you use `||`, the values being compared will be [converted to booleans](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), and `shipping_quotes` will evaluate to `false` whether it is an empty array or a `null`.

```
function wpsc_have_shipping_quote() {    

    global $wpsc_cart;

    return $wpsc_cart->shipping_quote_count || $wpsc_cart->shipping_quotes;
}
```

This should work in any PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

Andy. Kind regards.

In PHP 8.+, count() does not accept null values anymore, it was already throwing warnings since PHP 7.2 if I recall correctly. Therefore the code is failing exactly here:

`count( $wpsc_cart->shipping_quotes ) > 0`

because in some situations `$wpsc_cart->shipping_quotes` may be null (it was not set).

You can use the new PHP 8 null coalescing to check if the value is null, and if it is null, you can provide an empty array `[]`. So change the line:

```
if ( $wpsc_cart->shipping_quote_count > 0 || count( $wpsc_cart->shipping_quotes ) > 0 ) {
```

To:

```
if ( $wpsc_cart->shipping_quote_count > 0 || count( $wpsc_cart->shipping_quotes ?? [] ) > 0 ) {
```

Comment: Null coalescing operator was introduced with PHP 7 though.